# Editing Native Mac Applications

Tags: macos

Is it possible to write plugins or extensions that will edit/augment the native Mac applications?

For example, consider an extension like "weighted shuffle" for iTunes that shuffles songs in a way such that the chance of any song being selected is proportional to its play count divided by the total numbers of plays.

Is there a way to write a plugin that adds a feature like this to a native app? I would love to experiment with adding features like this.

Comment: That depends on the app. This isn't even specific to Mac or "native" apps. If the app has a plugin mechanism, then yes. If not, then maybe you can hack it, or maybe you can't feasibly.

Comment: Fire up "Automator" (Cmd+Space then Automator, Enter) and look and see what iTunes exposes to you to play with.

Comment: Ah, that stands to reason. Any suggestions on how to determine if a given Mac application has a plugin mechanism? Simple googling worked for iTunes, but there are fewer relevant results for other apps like Messages or Maps.

Answer (score 0):

AppleScript (including Scripting Bridge) and Accessibility.